# Why does Vertica query_requests table report that a query took a few milliseconds, while it actually took 10 seconds?

Tags: vertica

I'm running queries against a Vertica table with close to 500 columns and only 100 000 rows.

A simple query (like select avg(col1) from mytable) takes **10 seconds**, as reported by the Vertica vsql client with the \timing command.

But when checking column query_requests.request_duration_ms for this query, there's no mention of the 10 seconds, it reports less than **100 milliseconds**.

The query_requests.start_timestamp column indicates that the beginning of the processing started 10 seconds after I actually executed the command.

The resource_acquisitions table show no delay in resource acquisition, but its queue_entry_timestamp column also shows the queue entry occurred 10 seconds after I actually executed the command.

The same query run on the same data but on a table with only one column returns immediately. And since I'm running the queries directly on a Vertica node, I'm excluding any network latency issue.

It feels like Vertica is doing something before executing the query. This is taking most of the time, and is related to the number of columns of the table. Any idea what it could be, and what I could try to fix it ?

I'm using Vertica 8, in a test environment with no load.

Comment: I think its better if you will ask [Vertica](https://forum.vertica.com) forum. There are employees/develops/CTO, they can help better for Vertica internal "signals".

Comment: Thanks, I will. I may favour too much Stack Overflow.

Comment: My guess is that the `\timing` result includes sending the result from the server to the client.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It can be a problem with environment(sockets), but the difference is too much - x10(also its not a formatting issue). I agree with OP that something wrong is going here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the volume of data transfered was my initial hypothesis, but the query returns a single number, is executed locally on the server, and the execution time drops from 10 seconds to 100 milliseconds when the size of the table drops from 500 columns to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running Vertica 8.1.0-1, it seems the issue was caused by a Vertica bug in the query planning phase causing a performance degradation. It was solved in versions >= 8.1.1 : 
https://my.vertica.com/docs/ReleaseNotes/8.1./Vertica_8.1.x_Release_Notes.htm

> VER-53602 - Optimizer - This fix improves complex query performance during the query planning phase.